# Conditional Gravity Forms filter in WordPress Multisite

Tags: functions, multisite, conditional-tags

I'm using this technique:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323460/how-to-label-payments-in-gravity-forms-paypal-pro

To add comments to the paypal comments field from a gravity form. However, it's a multisite configuration. I'd like to modify it so the filter only triggers on blog_id 2

What's the proper method to make this conditional?

Much thanks.

Comment: @celso - mind weighing in?

Comment: FYI - pinging a user will only work if they've been active on this post. You'll need to ping them on their own post :)

Comment: Did you solve this Craig or do you still need an answer on the multi-site aspect?

Comment: I have not yet solved it.

Comment: @jdm2112 I have not solved it - do you have any insights you might be able to offer? It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @jdm2112 response, I did the following:

```
add_filter('gform_paypalpaymentspro_args_before_payment','add_donation_comment', 10, 2 );
function add_donation_comment( $args, $form_id ) { // do not edit $args or $form_id
    global $blog_id; // Make this available to the function

    // Apply filter only if blog id is 2
    if ( 2 == $blog_id ) {

        // apply to form 1 only
        if ( 1 == $form_id ) { // Replace '1' with your form id
                $args["COMMENT1"] = 'Field Project'; // Comment1 is the arg that paypal pro uses. 
        }
        // apply to form 2 only
        if ( 2 == $form_id ) { // Replace '2' with your form id
                $args["COMMENT1"] = 'Help Us Grow';
        }
        // always return the args, even if not changing anything 
        return $args;

    }       

    else {

        // always return the args, even if not changing anything 
        return $args;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the code from the answer you linked in your question (untested at present):

```
add_filter( 'gform_paypalpaymentspro_args_before_payment','add_donation_comment', 10, 2 );
function add_donation_comment( $args, $form_id ) { // do not edit $args or $form_id
    global $blog_id; // Make this available to the function

    // Apply filter only if blog id is 2
    if ( 2 !== $blog_id ) {
        return $args;
    }       

    // apply to form 1 only
    if ( 1 == $form_id ) { // Replace '1' with your form id
            $args["COMMENT1"] = 'Field Project'; // Comment1 is the arg that paypal pro uses. 
    }
    // apply to form 2 only
    if ( 2 == $form_id ) { // Replace '2' with your form id
            $args["COMMENT1"] = 'Help Us Grow';
    }
    // always return the args, even if not changing anything 
    return $args;
}
```

Adding the `global $blog_id` line makes this WP value available to the function.  As you know, it stores the site ID# in a multi-site install, allowing you to apply your filter on specific sites in your network.

The second addition is just a test of that value, written in the form of a [Yoda condition](https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/php/#yoda-conditions).  If this function is executing on any other site, the `$args` array is returned unchanged.

The rest of this code is exactly as found in the answer you referenced.

NOTE: I am unable to test this right now but I will be available later if you have any problems.  Cheers.

Comment: Fantastic. I was SO close ... thank you for clearing it up and being so willing to share your knowledge. I will test it now and report back.

Comment: Glad to help.  Let me know if this fails for any reason.

Comment: I had to make a slight adjustment (I cannot say why it didn't work as you wrote it, but...) I changed the `if ( 2 !== $blog_id )` to `==` and put the form specific conditions inside that condition, ending with `return $args`. Then I added an else that **just** returned the args.

Comment: Don't forget to post your answer so this one gets closed.  Thx